# loop through array of objects using ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a array of objects this way.

```js
0:
cardLast4Digits: "0664"
cardType: "GIFT_CARD"
__proto__: Object
1:
cardLast4Digits: "5551"
cardType: "CREDIT_CARD"
__proto__: Object
```

I want to loop through this array of object and find if cardType is "GIFT_CARD". Once i find it, i want to get that object as a result. Output should then be

```
0:
cardLast4Digits: "0664"
cardType: "GIFT_CARD"
__proto__: Object
```

Can someone please suggest me how to do this withv ramda.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate and closed? He specifically asks for a solution using Ramda, and the link to the previous answer doesn't do that.

Comment: `R.find(R.eqProps('GIFT_CARD', cardType), yourArrayOfObjects)`

Comment: @bdbdbd updated with a ramda duplicate. Please `@<username>` to notify a user.

Comment: @adiga thanks, I didn't know that and thanks for updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the array find method: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#find

**Ramda:**

```
const items = [{
  cardLast4Digits: '0664',
  cardType: 'GIFT_CARD'
}, {
  cardLast4Digits: '5551',
  cardType: 'CREDIT_CARD'
}];
R.find(R.propEq('cardType', 'GIFT_CARD'))(items);
```

**ES6:**

```js
const items = [{
  cardLast4Digits: '0664',
  cardType: 'GIFT_CARD'
}, {
  cardLast4Digits: '5551',
  cardType: 'CREDIT_CARD'
}];

const result = items.find(item => item.cardType === 'GIFT_CARD');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's still not using Ramda, but just the built in JS find method.

`R.find(R.eqProps('cardType', 'GIFT_CARD'))(items)` 
is the Ramda way.